# Constraints from code behave differently from interface builder

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, uikit

I'm moving part of UI to code from Interface Builder. After finishing, I'm comparing different branches in `Debug View Hierarchy` mode - the set of constraints look the same, except different constraints are grayed:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

What does this gray color mean? They all active. The issue is that the grayed constraint on the second picture doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gray color highlights the active constraints that *Auto Layout* is not using due to conflicts or because there are other higher priority constraints it is using.

The problem is that your constraints aren't quite the same.

**Before:**

```
superview.bottom = self.bottom + 200 @ 750
```

**After:**

```
self.bottom = superview.bottom + 200 @ 750
```

Those aren't the same.  To fix the *After* case, you either need to switch the `self.bottom` and `superview.bottom` items or change the constant to `-200`.

Comment: I struggled with this for quite a long time! so stupid mistake. thanks a lot!